# I cant install or update anything

Tags: upgrade

I have tried following previous questions but to no avail while running      *sudo apt-get upgrade* i get the following message

*After this operation, 48.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)*

I am a first time linux user so please be gentle I am just looking for an answer to my problem.

Comment: we are usually gentle here :D .. ok can you open a terminal window and type `sudo apt-get install -f` and if you get any errors could you post them in your question. If you want to have it format easy you can indent each line with 4 spaces and it will leave it in grey text background like `this`. I'm new to the forum and there may be a better way but I haven't found it yet :D

Comment: this is what I get:

    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
    evan@Evan-linux:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.'

Comment: I am trying to get used to all of this as I am going to school for IT and cyber security

Comment: can you run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` if you use ` to surround the text it will give you the gray highlighted background on the coded text. Thats the ` key .. the key next to the number 1 .. the key with the ~ but without hitting shift... lol I don't know what that "apostrophe" symbol is called :D

Comment: you can add the results to your question .. don't worry about the format if you don't understand but basically if you have 5 lines of text and you wanted them to all be printed as code with the gray background  you need to  add a separate line so the normal text has one blank line separating it then indent each full line with 4 spaces then add a blank line after the coded or pasted text ... be careful because if a line is 'wrapped' then  you don't have to add the 4 spaces on it ..dont worry if you cant figure it out I can edit it to clean it up if necessary

Comment: I am trying to use the apostrophe and it doesnt change but this is what I get

`W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
evan@Evan-linux:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a `

Comment: when i ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` i get nothing just moves down to the next line

Comment: give me a moment while i rack my brain and try to figure out a next step since we arent seeming to get any usable errors ... the errors about the ppas  can be removed by using Settings-Software & Updates and go to the other software  and uncheck those that were erroring

Comment: When you ran the command it told you .. did it immediately go to the next line or did it take a second or two... it may have run but had no output. Try running `sudo apt-get upgrade` again and see if you get the same error or something different

Comment: I tried running `sudo apt-get upgrade` again and it still gives me the same error  `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`  and it immediately just went to the next line no hesitation at all

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` .. unfortunately its not spitting out an error that is specific ... that error its printing isn't really giving me a direction as to what the error actually is...

Comment: Ok I'm at work now so I will give it a stable when I get home tonight and let you know what I get

Comment: ok I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` and this is what i get : 

`W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: tried to run the software updater and it tells me to check my internet connection....I am hard wired. this is what I get from that window
`W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: the failures aren't too important . basically you need to edit your sources and remove the ones giving you the Not Found errors .. those  sources just no longer exist. so we are still basically at square one .. we still have the error that doesn't actually point us to what is causing the error :( .. I'm at a loss but I will keep wracking my brain .. if i come up with something I'll let you know

Comment: easiest way to edit your sources is to go to the start menu and settings then Software & Updates .. Click on the Other Software tab and uncheck the offending addresses such as  `http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty`

Comment: Actually I just did a fresh install of 16.04 and no issues